# The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Error when retrieving Products with Features

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have a db with products looking like this:

[image: db schema]

I am trying to retrieve Products with the features based on the selected language.

When I try this:

```
    PromotedProducts = db.ProductLanguageDetail.
               Where(a => a.cls_Language.Language == language).
               Include(a => a.Product.ProductLanguageFeature).
               ToList();
```

I get the products for selected language, and also all the fetures for this products, but the features are not filtered by the language, so I get features in multiple languages.

When I try to filter the features:

```
    PromotedProducts = db.ProductLanguageDetail.
                Where(a => a.cls_Language.Language == language).
                Include(a => a.Product.ProductLanguageFeature.Where(feature => feature.IdLanguage == a.IdLanguage)).
                ToList();
```

I get an error:"The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path"

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What's the `language` in your query?

Comment: I would write a linq query with joins, easier to read. something like: `var PromotedProducts  = from ProductLanguageDetail in db.ProductLanguageDetail join ........` etc.

Comment: The variable language is just string like "en" which matches the the Language in cls_Language.

Comment: This is really the same..
         PromotedProducts = db.ProductLanguageDetail.
                    Where(a => a.cls_Language.Language == language).
                    Include(a => a.Product.ProductLanguageFeature).
                    Where(a => a.cls_Language.Language == language).
                    ToList();

Comment: I cannot reach the ProductLanguageFeature in the Where what is following the Include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing with EF entities and queries is that the entity structure should always be thought of as a complete representation of the data structure. This means that when you look at a product that has a relationship to features by language, the product entity should always have visibility to all of it's related data, it's never "filtered". This is one reason why you should avoid passing entities to views because you end up exposing more information about your schema than the view needs.

What it sounds like you want is a list of products that have at least 1 feature for a specified language, then to see only the features for that product that match that language.

As entities, this would be:

```
var promotedProducts = db.Products
    .Where(x => x.ProductLanguageFeatures.Any(f => f.LanguageId == language))
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        Product = x,
        Features = x.ProductLanguageFeatures.Where(f => f.LanguageId == language).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

This would give you a list of anonymous types containing the Products that have a feature for that language, and the applicable collection of features for that language.

To return that as a single structure I would recommend creating view models for the product and it's features:

```
[Serializable]
public class ProductViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public ICollection<ProductFeatureViewModel> Features { get; set;} = new List<ProductFeatureViewModel>();
}

[Serializable]
public class ProductFeatureViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Feature { get; set; }
}
```

Then load these up via projection:

```
var promotedProducts = db.Products
    .Where(x => x.ProductLanguageFeatures.Any(f => f.LanguageId == language))
    .Select(x => new ProductViewModel
    { 
        Id = x.Id,
        Features = x.ProductLanguageFeatures
            .Where(f => f.LanguageId == language)
            .Select(f => new ProductFeatureViewModel
            {
               Id = f.Id,
               Feature = f.Feature
            }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

That might look like a bit of boring code to have to write, but Automapper can help considerably with it's `ProjectTo` method.  This gives your view/consumer just the data that is applicable to it the way that makes sense for it.

Entities should reflect pure data state.
View models can reflect business / view state.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run query on `Product` to instruct how EF should construct the sub-query. Try code below.

```
PromotedProducts = db.ProductLanguageDetail.
            Where(a => a.cls_Language.Language == language).
            Include(a => a.Product
                .Select(p => p.ProductLanguageFeature.Where(feature => feature.IdLanguage == a.IdLanguage))).
            ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

> Unfortunately I cannot use Select after Product..

As you didn't provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I am just guessing here, but based on the relationship you should do following query as you are only interested in those object with particular language.

```
PromotedProducts = db.cls_Language
            .Where(l => l == language)
            .Select(l => new {
                Lanugage = l,
                ProductDetail = l.ProductLanguageDetail,
                Product = l.ProductLanguageDetail.Product,
                ProductLanguageFeature = l.ProductLanguageFeature
            }
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => x.ProductDetail);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use Select after Product..
http://cloud1.identigen.com/images/Screenshot_2.png

Comment: @PetrŽampach: Try updated version. That should work even it is not ideal.